# how to show blank record in table using freemarker

Tags: freemarker

i have a attribute worktime in my database table which is integer it has value as `0` , i want to show  the blank record in the  table using freemarker.  how to do that?

```
<#list empAttendanceStatus as employee>
    <td>${employee.worktime!""}</td>
</#list>
```

Comment: Doesn't your example work OK?  What happens?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your field is Java type of "Integer", if that is the case, using ! will only show blank if the integer is null.  If your using int, it will always initialize to be zero, so there is no concept of blank or empty.

If you want to show blank when the Integer is 0, then you need to use an if statement.

```
<#if integer != 0>
   ${integer}
</#if>
```

I am guessing, maybe you want to display 0 when a users enters 0, and blank when a user doesn't enter anything?  If that is the case, you must use "Integer", and use null to represent nothing entered.